# How to show Default Android Messages like (+) button and show custom widget in place of keyboard in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I implement default android Messages like a custom widget in place of the keyboard shown in the GIF?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tap on *+* button, what happens is,

- Keyboard Closed, to achieve this you can use `FocusNode` instance and assign in `TextField`, to *unfocus* or to *close* keyboard, you can achieve it by `focusNode.unfocus()`.
- The content you see on tap of *+* is outside keyboard, i.e. you have to create widget and change it's visibility accordingly, `Visibility` can be used.
- In other case misc options is visible and user tap on keyboard icon then change visibility of extra options and obtain focus of `FocusNode` instance(enable keyboard), by `focusNode.requestFocus()`.

Comment: yaaa! but how can I ensure that my text field will be above my custom widgets?

Comment: Let suppose you're using column, then you have to set sequence of `Widget` (which consists misc options) right after the input field `Widget`.